# Mongo query not recording (too large) and crashes

Tags: php, mongodb, cron

I have a couple of crons running every minute. each has 14 to 20 mongo queries running. Sometimes the mongo log displays "Mongo query not recording (too large)" and crashes. "not recording" means its just too large to be showed in the log. But the crashing situation is my problem.

1. How do i overcome this crashing?
2. Is it because im running all these crons at once?
3. will spreading the cron job workload help?
4. I also have $where functions going on in queries. is it a bad thing?

Comment: It will be helpful if you post a relevant code too.

Comment: I wish i could. Im not allowed to share code from where i work.

Comment: Then make something up but keep the relevant parts. Such as sending lots of things to `$in` within a loop. Or is part of your problem actually identifying which query in the code is actually causing this?

Comment: This question needs an example for it to be answered. Might also be better suited on http://dba.stackexchange.com/